# Как определить язык программирования?

Tags: декомпиляция, обратная-разработка

Здравствуйте!
Меня очень интересует вопрос, как можно определить язык программы, если она уже откомпилирована?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это, на самом деле, дело не из легких, поверьте! С супер точностью определить ничего не получится, так как языки могут быть разные, поддерживаемые, скажем одной средой программирования( VS, например, в которой поддерживается разработка на свыше 10 языках), а та, в свою очередь, добавляет сходную последовательность asm-секций в машинный код любого приложения, написанного в этой среде. Поэтому, скажем, с точностью( и то не всегда 100%-ой! ) можно определить среду разработки.
Делается это, естественно, под дезассемблером. Лучший на мой взгляд( и где я, кстати, чаше всего провожу отладку ) - это **[OllyDBG](http://popprograms.com/399-ollydbg.html)**. Под ним очень легко и быстро можно разобрать почти любую софтину( за исключением упакованой, обфусцированной и т.д ). Так, VS, например, добавляет в ассемблерный код несколько секций, порядок которых специфичен для данной среды. Последовательность похожа на эту( только пример! ), насколько я помню:

```
.686 
.model flat, c 
option casemap :none

; «««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««

.data

; «««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««

.code

MyFunc PROC uses ecx edi, X: DWORD, Y:DWORD 
; TODO

ret 
MyFunc ENDP
```

Answer (score 4):

Самое простое и быстрое для вас решение - взять PeID и проанализировать им исполняемый файл. Если программа без защит, есть шансы успешного определения.

Comment: Nofate, действительно хорошая и быстрая программа. Я уже её видел и она очень часто не справляется с определением языка, но всё-равно спасибо за ответ (палец вверх вам :)